# Sports Commentary Feed Authoring Software

Tags: cms, sport

I am looking for software that will allow a timeline feed to be generated around match events.

The style is similar to the “Storify” news room type solution, with some differences that Storify does not produce today.

Essentially we would want:

1. The “story” itself to be the match, and a series of events occurring down a timeline.
2. Each event would be a distinct content bubble that would be able to contain specific component based layouts. I.e. a chunk of HTML with a corresponding CSS, that is able to be authored through a simple process.
3. The event would also need to be automatically submitted to social media.
4. The event could be of N number of customisable events such as “Red Card”, “Yellow Card”, “Goals” etc
5. Events can be originated either from the authors in the match box, or from an upstream feed such as [Opta Sports](http://www.optasports.com/services/media/data-feeds/opta-data-feeds-overview.aspx)
6. When events are received from upstream, they can be further enriched by the authors.
7. Customisable authorable components, so that a new event can be added quickly with all or partial details.
8. Video and Audio Components, or the ability to produce custom components
9. Video and Audio CDN an advantage, at minimum able to be integrated with services such as Ooyala, Brightcove, Adobe Dynamic media etc.

Does anyone know of something that covers this list, or is customisable from the box, or is it all just a pure custom job?

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering a custom solution it might be worth you taking a look at [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) and some of the associated projects such as those listed under the [VideoGrep](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/gallery.html#videogrep) entry in the [Gallery](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/gallery.html).  You would also do well to look at [this blog post](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/07/04/automatic-soccer-highlights-compilations-with-python/) uses MoviePy to automatically cut together all the highlights of a soccer game, based on the fact that the crowd cheers louder when something interesting happens. All in under 30 lines of Python.

The above are all [python](https://www.python.org/) based libraries that work with the [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) & [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) libraries, *amongst others*.  Python includes a number of components, either as a part of the standard library or as extension libraries, that can handle tasks such as connecting to various services, feeds, etc.

All of the software mentioned above is Free, Gratis & Open Source.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions for video processing. These will be helpful for another use case, however, what I am looking for is a football match timeline. This is basically a set of content blobs like a twitter feed, which contain media elements, as well as text and image.

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think the question asks for any kind of automated recognition, right? Just events coming from externally-provided live feeds and manual text entry.

Comment: There is no fancy recognition required. What we would like is to be able to essentially tag the event as a type, and then be able to render it out as a different CSS class. Unfortunately, Storify 2, which is what we were looking at does not afford us this capability, as it does not have a custom HTML pipe, and no way to discern between different event types. It's built as a news feed with updates, not as a timeline with events of differing types and displays.